# Bundle Update downgrades several gems in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Disclaimer before reading: I have resolved this issue but I am asking because I still don't know the reasons behind it.

I'm working on an old gem that pulls assets into the asset pipeline.  I'm not positive how the gem was originally created I imagine it was with `rails plugin new static_assets`.
Since it is a gem the Gemfile is not overly complex (I haven't made any changes to it):

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gemspec

# jquery-rails is used by the dummy application
gem "jquery-rails"
```

But the Gemfile.lock has dozens of gems and dependencies showing up.  For the most part, the gems seem up to date.

When I run a `bundle update` several of the gems go back to much older versions; like Rails 5 to Rails 3.

I believe I solved this by updating the Gemfile to 
`gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.3'`
but I want to know why this was happening.

I'm not overly familiar with how Gemfile.lock gets created and updated but I was under the impression that it was based on the Gemfile, pulling all gems and their dependencies from the Gemfile.  If all the gems in Gemfile.lock are dependant on `jquery-rails` why was it automatically downgrading them so unilaterally and by so much?

Comment: This should "never happen". Which means something weird went on here. Is that the **full** `Gemfile` that you're showing us? Was the `Gemfile.lock` valid previously, or was there a dependency incompatibility? The "fix" you've shown shouldn't have changed anything!

Comment: That's the whole Gemfile...  And previously there was no dependency incompatibility that I know of.